# Stop receiving some emails from WP site

Tags: php, wordpress, email, reporting-services, gmail

We are running video website on WordPress for more than 1 year. We are collecting some data about activity on our website and send them as various reports. Some reports are sent once per day, other reports are sent when user make some activity (e.g. data from payment gateway after user purchased premium content, etc...)

Suddenly, some of these daily reports are not receiving on email addresses with two custom domains (some-user@my-domain.com). After I changed email addresses to our GMAIL accounts, everything works fine, so it is very strange... We are receiving irregular reports on our custom domain addresses (together with lot of other emails from website including WordPress reports like new user registered, Wordfence activity reports etc...), but we are not receiving regular daily reports...

All these emails are sent via wp_mail() function and function is returning always true. We are not doing any changes in our code or server settings for last couple of weeks.

Summary:
Before October 24th: All reports emailed to some-user@my-domain.com are received without any problems for more than one year.

After October 24th: Only some reports emailed to some-user@my-domain.com are received, but we are able to received other reports only to some-user@gmail.com.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: have you checked the junk/spam folder of the recipient addresses?

Comment: @bushell - thanks for your reply, yes we checked spam folders and messages were not there.